# how to distinguish files from directories in moveItemAtPath:toPath:error: method

Tags: objective-c

the declaration of this methos is:
- (BOOL)moveItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error
and its docs say that the source path can be a file name or a dir name, suppose we have in the current working directory, a file named "test" and a sub-directory named "test", after calling the method: 
[fm moveItemAtPath: @"test" toPath: @"newTest" error:null];

where fm is an object of NSFileManager class, which of the items going to be renamed : the file or the directory ? how does this method distinguish files from directories ?

p.s. as far as I know, this method does a rename if the source and target paths are the same, in this case, source path = target path = current working directory.

Comment: What is you target OS? The file system used in Mac OS X and iOS (HFS), does not allow creating files and directories with the same name

Comment: Target OS is Windows 7 ... I got the idea now, and as @sidyll said, if I provide as argument "file" the method will consider it as directory, and if provide "file.txt" it will consider it as file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @stam said, you can't create a file and a folder with the same name (please keep in mind that `file.txt` is different from `file`).

But, if you want to know whether a path represents a directory or a file, use the following method:

```
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory
```

Like in:

```
BOOL isDir;
if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir]) {
    // Item Exists
    if (isDir) {
        // Is a directory
    } else {
        // Is a file
    }
} else {
    // Item doesn't exist
}
```